# How to play multiple youtube video into single player.

Tags: javascript, html, web, youtube

for example i have 4 youtube video id and want to be playing sync. means when first is end the second will play so on.. upto last.

currently using this kind of url https://www.youtube.com/v/LIQsyHoLudQ and want to load the multiple videos either with the embed tag or iframe.

i follow the develope https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?csw=1#playlist
but not getting how it will happen ?

Thanks
Rahul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do that with the playlist parameter, as you said. For example:

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/v/LIQsyHoLudQ?version=3&loop=1&playlist=BKfcEdMO380,wLx5OGxOYUc"></iframe>
```

The playlist parameter takes a comma separated list of video IDs.

Comment: thanks for help. i try this way but have confused about how to play  random among the list. e.i. I have three video and want to play no 2 on click of any button.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding multiple VIDEO_ID in compa seprate with query string ?
like `http://www.youtube.com/embed/LIQsyHoLudQ?enablejsapi=1&autoplay=1&playlist=VIDEO_ID1,VIDEOID2`

and for random you are saying like

`public int GetRandom { return 2; }`

It doesn't make any sense.